# Profile/Transect tool in QGIS like Arc's interpolate transect tool?

Tags: qgis, line, profile

I am quite new to GIS.
I am trying to determine the values along a transect of a raster in QGIS. I can perform this task in ArcMap using the profile tool however I've tried several methods in QGIS (profile tool, point sampling tool) but do not seem to work!
FYI, I'm looking at LST data and using QGIS 2.18.15 for Mac.

Comment: Profile tool plugin could do the job. Do you retrieve an error using it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! it is hard to get an idea about the kind of problem you are facing based on your question. Please provide more information and you will find more people willing to help you. What is your input data? What have you tried especifically? What did it go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools for retrieve profiles, but among them there are two great ones in QGIS 2.18 that are my favorites, one for raster data and the other for points:

1. [Profile tool](https://github.com/etiennesky/profiletool): it gets the profile along a line from raster. It can use a temporary line or a selected line from a line layer.
2. [ProfileFromPoints](https://github.com/msweier/QGIS-Profile-from-Points-Plugin): it interpolates points on a point layer along a selected line.

Both plugins expect projected data to calculate the distance, no suited for geography coordinates.